# Modal not disappearing

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning react, I have a popup on the screen and added logic to make it disappear, however it is not working and I don't know why. Can anyone help?

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Modal from './Modal';
import Backdrop from './Backdrop';

function Todo(props) {
const [modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState();

   function deleteHandler(){
      {setModalIsOpen(true);}
   }

 return (
   <div className="card">
     <h2>{props.text}</h2>
     <div className="actions">
       <button className="btn" onClick={deleteHandler}>Delete</button>
     </div>
     {modalIsOpen ? <Modal /> : null}
     {modalIsOpen ? <Backdrop /> : null}
   </div>
 );
}

export default Todo;
```

This show makes the modal false at the beginning however, if I launch the website the modal is there straight away.

Comment: What is the initial state of your modal? Let react know what the initial state is. Set the initial state of your modal to false. `const [modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState(false)`

Comment: You have an extra set of braces around setModalIsOpen(true)

Comment: ive added the `  const [modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState(false) ` and it still doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the above snippet with some changes.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Modal from './Modal';
import Backdrop from './Backdrop';

function Todo(props) {
    const {text} = {...props}
    const [modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState(false);

    const deleteHandler =()=> {
       setModalIsOpen(false)
    }

    return (
     <div className="card">
       <h2>{text}</h2>
       <div className="actions">
         <button className="btn" onClick={deleteHandler}>Delete</button>
       </div>
       {modalIsOpen && <Modal /> }
       {modalIsOpen && <Backdrop />}
     </div>
   );
}

export default Todo;
```

Comment: the modal is still open, idk why. I have even removed rhe last part of the code and it still pops up and i dont referance it anywhere else

Comment: Ohh. could you try restarting the project. i can't find any issue here.

Comment: i have lol, about 300 times. This is very weird.

Comment: could you provide your code in a code sandbox, so that i can look into it

Comment: ill upload it to github gimme 5 min and thanks

Comment: https://github.com/Kroplewski-M/React-Todo-

Comment: full code is here, thanks

Comment: remove `Model` and `Backdrop` from `App.js`

Comment: there is a Modal call in App.js, try removing that

Comment: i have removed it, and updated github but for some reason its not getting the changes, i think there might be a problem with my project files or something

Comment: I can't see any changes to you github :)

Comment: it has worked, wow im an idiot, wheni made all the changes in a few files, i always clicked ctr + s and that only saved one file and not all of them. It works now. thanks

Comment: OK Great!. Happy learning! please up-vote if you found the answers are helpful

Answer (score 0):

You should intitialize modalIsOpen to false and then if you want to close the modal you should set to false not to true.

```
function deleteHandler(){
          setModalIsOpen(false);
       }
```

Comment: i have and same thing

Answer (score 0):

change `setModalIsOpen(true);` to `setModalIsOpen(false);` on `deleteHandler` function